# Is "I did not breakfast today" correct?

Tags: etymology, grammaticality, verbs, formality

Is the following sentence correct?

> I did not breakfast today

Due to *breakfast* coming from ‘to break your fast’.

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to verb breakfast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Yes it comes from a verb, but it has long since been reanalysed as a noun. If you read old novels you might find it used as a verb, as in *they breakfasted on sweetmeats and gruel* or *they were hungry, not having breakfasted*, but I think it's fair to say that use is now obsolete. If you hear it, you can be pretty sure there's some kind of joke / olde-worlde role play going on - so you could say it's no longer correct, or you could say it is correct but archaic.

Comment: Far from being obsolete, the past tense "breakfasted" is quite common. *In July, 2009, Obama went to Moscow, **where he breakfasted** on caviar…* See link https://www.google.com/search?q=%22breakfasted%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT6L295JLhAhXB0aQKHcnqC6QQ_AUIESgE&biw=1316&bih=647

Comment: RIght, it is marked as literary today. That said, if you enjoy peppering your speech with old-fangled things, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is more commonly said to **have** or **eat** breakfast. A lesser used, though perfectly acceptable verb is to **take**, as in the phrase:

What time would you like to take lunch?

*or*

Where will you be taking supper this evening?

Answer (score 0):

There is some use of breakfast like that in what I would call formal English (ie. “Where would you like to breakfast/lunch etc. today?”), but generally no. You would commonly say “I did not have breakfast today”, or “I missed breakfast”.

Or as pointed out in a comment, as a formal use in past tense. That use is uncommon outside of a newspaper and in less formal English would probably be replaced with the word “eat” or “ate”. “They ate cavier”.